# Mid-2012 Retina Pro - shouldn't I have Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

I recently reinstalled OSX, Win7 and Linux on my mid-2012 15" Retina (purchased August 19, 2012), and just noticed that I, apparently, am now running OSX Lion (10.7.5).

I recall that this machine came with Mountain Lion. I'm not sure exactly how this happened, but the only fix I have in mind at the moment is to do an internet recovery, which I *hope* will get the system back to ML; but, I'd rather not have to back up and restore 500+GB of Linux and Windows stuff in order to get a 4GB installer to download.

Suggestions?

**Update**

Forced internet recovery, which also says Lion instead of ML. Going to try nuking the recovery partition to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on when you purchased it, it's possible that your machine came with OS X Lion preinstalled and you got the free upgrade to OS X Mountain Lion in July 2012. [Apple's press release on the Mid-2012 MacBook Pro Retina](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2012/06/11Apple-Introduces-All-New-MacBook-Pro-with-Retina-Display.html) dated June 11, 2012 states:

> The all new MacBook Pro ships with OS X Lion. Starting today, customers who purchase a Mac are eligible for a free copy of OS X Mountain Lion when it becomes available.

You can just visit the Mac App Store, sign in and install OS X Mountain Lion from there.

Comment: Tried that; App Store wants me to pay $20 for ML. I am positive that I had ML on here before the reinstall. I'm almost positive ML came installed when this machine was new. The only other thing that comes to mind is that I used the OSX Recovery Assistant when rebuilding the drive. Maybe it convinced the machine that it came with Lion. Argh.

Comment: Hmm, so if you're sure you didn't follow the up-to-date process to get a free redemption code for OS X Mountain Lion (from MAS) through email, you should just call Apple.
The process of redemption is described here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/bought-mac-claim-free-upgrade-os-mountain-lion/

Comment: Yeah, definitely didn't do that. This is also my third retina (replaced under warranty for hardware issues). Surely they would have given me one with ML. (Most recent was about 4 months ago.) Ill call them. Thanks.

Comment: So, just got off the phone with Apple. They say that the machine came with Lion, I've never had ML, and that, despite the free update that was advertised about the time I bought the machine, I'll have to buy it. Starting to think I'm crazy, except for: I installed XCode from the App Store last week, which *requires* ML.